# First row skipped in CSV import to dataframe

Tags: octave

I have a problem regarding the import of a simple csv file.
I use publicly available data from eurostat on quarterly gdp data for Greece.

I import the data using the following command:

```matlab
gdp_greece = dataframe([myenv,"namq_10_gdp_1_Data.csv"]);
```

When I import it correctly identifies the header but then leaves out the first row, which is the data entry for 1995Q1. It only identifies 1995Q2 and onward.

The first three lines of the csv file looks like this:

```
"TIME","GEO","UNIT","S_ADJ","NA_ITEM","Value","Flag and Footnotes"
"1995Q1","Greece","Chain linked volumes, index 2010=100","Seasonally and calendar adjusted data","Gross domestic product at market prices","72.5",""
"1995Q2","Greece","Chain linked volumes, index 2010=100","Seasonally and calendar adjusted data","Gross domestic product at market prices","73.2",""
```

So when I check for the first entry of the dataframe with: `gdp_greece(1,1)` the command window gives me `"1995Q2"`. Why is that and how can I avoid it?

I now imported the same data starting at `1994Q4` in order for Octave to omit line 1 and start from the desired `1995Q1` but the problem is, that I don't know if this behaviour is only on my computer. I have to hand this project in at university but if my professor executes my code and it identifies `1994Q4` as the first row then the code is not right anymore and my calculations are all wrong.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? I would be super grateful. I have looked into Octave documentation and searched for similar problems but could not find any. Any help is massively appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32552641/5211833 does this solve your problem?

Comment: I can reproduce your behaviour, so it's not just you. I'll look into it, but in general you might want to try `csv2cell` from the `io` package instead of the 'dataframe' one, since that's not really how the latter is supposed to be used. `csv2cell` deals with non-numeric csv files nicely.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author, maintainer and lonely contributor of the "dataframe" package. In your case, the problem is quite simple. The two first lines MAY contain variable names and variable types. So your second line is "eaten" by this process.

I started writing "dataframe" because I wished to have something similar to the same concept in R. Then MatLAB implemented two approaches to read CSV with meta information, the last one being the 'table' object. By lack of manpower I couldn't keep up with the development. So you're welcome to step in.

OTOH ... if you're working on big data sets, then R would be better suited. There is in particular a new integrated set of toolboxes as described in https://bookdown.org/ndphillips/YaRrr/

Regards

Pascal

Comment: Hi Pascal! Thank you for taking the time to create an SO account and explain the issue! I have replied separately [on the octave bug tracker](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?60138) regarding your thoughts on this issue, but for what it's worth, I wanted to say here that I didn't mean to cause offense or disappointment with my reply below. It is clear that the dataframe package is a huge endeavour, especially for a one-man-army, so it's natural that bugs will occur. Users finding bugs is not a bad thing: it means the software is useful and people like it! Please keep up the good work :)

Comment: thanks so much for the feedback! I managed eventually with csv2cell but yeah I would love to have something in matlab that is related to the dataframe concept of R, keep up the good work I hope you'll find the manpower to continue!

Answer (score 0):

**update**

You are encountering a [known bug](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?56263), which has been fixed in the development repositories, but is yet unreleased.

In theory, you could try to install the dataframe package from the [dev sources](https://sourceforge.net/p/octave/dataframe/ci/default/tree/), since these contain the fix already. Also, the author of the package has just replied to your post, so hopefully he may create a new release that can be downloaded from octave-forge as normal :)

Having said that, there is another bug here, which is the incorrect handling of elements that are quoted strings containing a comma. I have submitted this as a separate bug on here: ([bug #60138](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?60138)).

For this reason, I would instead collect the data from your csv file using the excellent `cell2csv` from the `io` package, and then process it directly via the resulting cell array.

If it helps you, you can convert this further into a struct array, or even a single struct containing cell/numerical arrays as members, which is effectively what a dataframe is in other languages.

Alternatively, if you're still keen to use the dataframe package because of existing functionality that it provides, you can feed the resulting cell directly into `dataframe` (obviously, after having applied the fix for the first bug mentioned above), i.e. `dataframe( csv2cell( "data.csv" ));` instead of just `dataframe( "data.csv" );`. This should parse the quoted elements correctly and bypass [bug #60138](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?60138). :)

Comment: thanks a lot its really good to hear that I am not hallucinating. Ευχαριστω πολυ Τάσο. Με βοηθησες πολυ. I will try to use cell2csv definitely!

Comment: @msz14: I had a look at the octave bug-tracker, and it turns out this is a known bug, which has been fixed in the development repositories but somehow never made it into a formal release ... https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=56263 They also explain why the bug happens there (an 'all strings second column' was interpreted as the variable types. The fix now checks if those strings refer to valid character type strings first). E.g. removing the quotes around your numerical field's (i.e. "Value") values (i.e. convert `"72.3"` to `72.3`, e.g. in a text editor) should work.

Comment: ... or, you could try downloading and installing the development version. Or stick with the `csv2cell` approach :p

Comment: incidentally, if this answer helps / answers your question, please consider upvoting / marking as correct :)

Comment: PS. I have reported another octave bug based on your question. Thanks for such a useful question! https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?60138